# MS-SQLSERVER - SQL Query using ROW_NUMBER taking long time with 0 result from query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
select autoid from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER 
BY MYTABLE.DETECTEDUTC DESC) as rownum, autoId from 
MYTABLE where MYTABLE.guid in (..guids..)) as tab1 where rownum >=1000 and rownum < 1020
```

We are having a table MYTABLE which may contain millions of records currently it is having 10 million records.
above SQL query used to get paginated data in our code, it works fine till query giving results, but hangs for hours if query returning 0 results.
Also SQL server start consuming system RAM while running above query and which is not returning any record.

on the other hand following query works fine with 0 results -

```
select autoid from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER 
BY MYTABLE.DETECTEDUTC DESC) as rownum, autoId from 
MYTABLE where MYTABLE.guid in( ..guids..)) as tab1
```

Comment: I can't fathom how either query could ever return any result?! The condition `where EVENTS.guid = NEWID()` should always evaluate to `false`.

Comment: query is just modified to check for no result scenerio

Comment: now changed the query to original one.

Comment: What are you testing ? SQL Server ? IF you are testing SQL Server then I suggest you check the execution plan - this usually gives you some hint what it is actually doing...

Comment: Can you try to run only the inner query? Is that the one that takes forever?

Comment: using ms-sqlserver, but query plan is same for all cases.

Comment: @CyberDude inner query alone working fine. also as i mentioned in my post full query without where clause on rowNum is also working fine

Comment: @coder: Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: as per query plan 90% of time is consumed in key lookup which is ok

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the issue in the query I am presenting the way I usually achieve paging:

As input (for a stored procedure for instance):

```
@fromIndex int = 0 -- default starting from index 0
@count int = 10 -- default returning 10 items per page
```

Generic SQL logic:

```
CREATE TABLE #PaginatedItems (
    Column1 int, -- declare your needed columns here
    Column2 varchar(50),
    rowIndex int -- needed for pagination logic
);

WITH OrderedItems AS
    (
        SELECT
            SourceTable.Col1, -- will end up in #PaginatedItems.Column1
            SourceTable.Col2,
            ROWNUMBER() OVER (
                                 ORDER BY <sort criteria>
                             ) AS rowIndex
        FROM
            SourceTable
    )
INSERT INTO
    #PaginatedItems
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OrderedItems
WHERE
    rowIndex >= @fromIndex + 1 AND rowIndex <= @fromIndex + @count

SELECT * FROM #PaginatedItems -- the query that returns the items
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you insert the results into a temp table, instead of returning them directly? If so, it might be worth adding an explanation for it into your answer.

Comment: No reason directly related to the subject. I am doing more joins for selecting extra information and using the temp table is faster in my case. I guess here it only helps a bit with readability.

Comment: i have tried above query without insert, still facing the same issue

Comment: Can you not manually exclude the 0 results case? IF (@fromIndex > SELECT COUNT(*) )...

Comment: no, as in normal cases result may have lacks of records and count(*) takes time in that case.